# Can someone explain to me why I'm having this error?

Tags: java

Good day,

I have a question on which in my code, one declaration is having an error outside a function.

The snippet is:

```
public class Gold {

    Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];
       
  
        this.block[1][4] = new Block(); //1
      
    
        public void populate() {
            this.block[1][4] = new Block();//2
    }
          
}
```

The code  `this.block[1][4] = new Block();` number 2 is not having an error. However, the first code which is not inside the function is showing the error:

> Illegal start type
>
> Cannot find symbol
>
> ']' expected
>
> invalid method declaration, return type required.

I just want to understand why this is hapenning and what I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no element with index 4. The last element has index 3.

Comment: Yeah, about that. I forgot to change that part when making this post.

Comment: @assylias: I know but the correct solution was already given when I posted. I wanted to prevent the next question :)

Answer (score 4):

You can not initialize variables directly as you did above in case 1, You can initialize `block[][]` in constructor like :

```
public Gold(){
    this.block[1][3] = new Block();
}
```

OR in block like :

```
Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];
{
      this.block[1][3] = new Block();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a statement which must be in a block of code.

Try

```
public class Gold {
    Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];
    { // initializer block
        this.block[1][3] = new Block(); //1
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems here, You need to initialize any object in a scope. Either you have to call the Number 1 line `in a constructor or in a function or with in a block (enclosed with in`{`and`}`)`. Here you need to know difference between `static block` and `non-static blocks`.

Other problem you have is `this.block[1][4] = new Block();` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutofBounds` exception as the length of the array is 4 and you are trying to insert  and object at 5th place.

Comment: Got it. In the second problem, I forgot to fix that when making this post. :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should place your code  in constructor:

```
public Gold(){
    this.block[1][4] = new Block();
}
```

In java class you can define variables or methods (including constructors) but can not use plain code in it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your code in a method, not in the class body. If its part of the initialization of the `Gold` class put it inside its constructor like:

```
public class Gold {

    Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];

    public Gold() {
          this.block[1][4] = new Block();
    }

}
```

The class body allows only variable declaration and instantiations, but not standard operations like changing an object's (your array) value.

EDIT: as other pointed out, the index `4` does not exist in an array of size `4`, only indices from `0` to `3` can be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.block[1][4] = new Block(); //1
```

is an expression not a field initialization. It cannot be outside of a method body.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence

```
this.block[1][4] = new Block(); //1
```

cannot go outside a method or Initialisation block. If you want to initialize the array you have to do it on the declaration or inside a method (constructor could be a good place) or you have to use a Initialisation block.

Also check the array bounds. In Java arrays have 0 based indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The code `this.block[1][4] = new Block()` is compiled but will fail on runtime: your array has 4 elements while index in java and all C-like languages starts from 0, so the max value of 4-elements long array is 3.

And you cannot write code outside methods in java, so if you try this you get compilation error.